# Text align in streamlit st.info information box

Tags: python, streamlit

How to align text **(justify)** in `streamlit` information box([st.info](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/status/st.info))

```
import streamlit as st

# Generate Three equal columns
c1, c2, c3 = st.columns((1, 1, 1))

with c1:
    st.info("""Streamlit is more than just a way to make data apps, it's also a community of creators that share their apps and ideas and help each other make their work better. Please come join us on the community forum. We love to hear your questions, ideas, and help you work through your bugs — stop by today!""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply a style.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st

mystyle = '''
    <style>
        p {
            text-align: justify;
        }
    </style>
    '''

st.markdown(mystyle, unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Generate Three equal columns
c1, c2, c3 = st.columns((1, 1, 1))

with c1:
    st.info("""Streamlit is more than just a way to make data apps, 
            it's also a community of creators that share their apps 
            and ideas and help each other make their work better. Please 
            come join us on the community forum. We love to hear your questions, 
            ideas, and help you work through your bugs — stop by today!""")
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Will this style apply to all(st.info, st.text, st.error etc...)??

Comment: You have to test it. My solution is only based on what you posted.